# Access denied to phpmyadmin with xampp

Tags: apache, phpmyadmin, xampp

I have a problem when I try to access to phpmy Admin via `localhost/phpmyadmin`. I know that this problem already exists but with all the methods that I found, it still doesn't work.

So I found the method where we need to change the file **httpd-xampp.config** :

> Alias /phpmyadmin "/xampp/phpMyAdmin/"
>
> < Directory "/xampp/phpMyAdmin">
>
> AllowOverride AuthConfig Limit
>
> Order allow,deny
>
> Allow from all
>
> Require all granted
>
> < /Directory >

But it doesn't work.

I also found an other soluce with the file **config.inc.php** but I don't find the file in my repository.

I don't know what to do, some help please !

Comment: What is the problem when you try to access it? Is there an error message?

Answer (score 0):

What version are you using? Try to find the following in httpd-xampp.config

```
<LocationMatch "^/(?i:(?:xampp|security|licenses|phpmyadmin|webalizer|server-status|server-info))">
Require local
Require ip 192.168
ErrorDocument 403 /error/XAMPP_FORBIDDEN.html.var
```

Comment: I'm using v3.2.1 (xampp). I tried to add what you said and reboot xampp but it doesn't work :/

Comment: What happens if you try the following?

<LocationMatch “^/(?i:(?:xampp|security|licenses|phpmyadmin|webalizer|server-status|server-info))”>
Order deny,allow
Allow from all
Allow from ::1 127.0.0.0/8
ErrorDocument 403 /error/XAMPP_FORBIDDEN.html.var
</LocationMatch>

Comment: Denied again. Is it normal that The repertory phpmyadmin was in **C:\xampp\mysql\data\phpmyadmin** and not in **C:\xampp\phpmyadmin**. I copied this file to **C:\xampp\phpmyadmin** but I don't know if it works this way :/